# Android send SMS with free sms plan

Tags: android, sms

I have a very strange issue: my apps can send text message and many users reports they pay the sms even when their subscription can send sms for free. The sms is sended to a national phonenumber, a classic smartphone (a friend).

Here the code:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    MyLog.log("send message to " + phoneNumber + " string: " + message);

}
```

I asked my carrier (WIND ITALY) what the problem was, and they told me that it seems that the number was international and the sms plan do not cover the international sms.

The numbers that I've tried are all local, no one is international. Change a Carrier is not the solution ... i try this with all of the national carrier.

Someone out there have an advice ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing you could do that would affect the payment or not of a given SMS. Possible explanations: a bug in your app that sends the message to the wrong number; the target number is not a standard number and is charged differently

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the app send the message correctly, i tell you this because the message is received from the other phone. The target number have the national prefix, maybe i can try to remove the prefix... and see what happend ... :)

Comment: maybe it sends the message to that number *and* other numbers too.

Comment: Pedro ... i don't think so ... since i'am the developer and i know what the app do ... (hope so) :)